# Zsh update variable inside child process

Tags: shell, zsh

In Zsh 5.2, `a=0 | a=1 | b=1; echo $a` will return 1, but `a=0 | (( a++ )) | b=1; echo $a` will return 0. Why?

As for my understanding, `|` creates child process, and to update `a` in child process should not be reflected in the parent process. This is true for `(( a++ ))` case, but how to explain the `a=1` case?

I explicitly added `b=1` as last part of the pipeline because in Zsh, the last pipe will be executed in parent process (from here: https://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=178,

> In Bash, all elements in a pipeline will run in a subshell. In Ksh and
>   Zsh, all except the last will run in a subshell. POSIX leaves it
>   undefined.

). I want to create a scenario that the update of `a` is in child process.

Comment: Try `a=5; a=0 | (( a++ )) | b=1; echo $a` -- you'll see that `a=5` on the other end. Which is to say, your `a=0` within the pipeline isn't actually doing anything that persists to the parent shell at all: Presumably when you got a contrary test result, it was already `0` before the code began.

Comment: BTW, bash *does* have a `lastpipe` option in modern releases, though it's only conditionally enabled (has to be explicitly turned on, and monitor mode / job control needs to be turned off).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In Zsh, ```a=5; a=0 | (( a++ )) | b=1; echo $a```returns 0, not 5.

Comment: Not in zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) as distributed out-of-the-box with MacOS High Sierra -- I absolutely get 5 every time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My version is ```zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0)```

Comment: ah, the fun of code that depends on undefined behavior. :) -- which is to say, writing code that makes assumptions about things that POSIX doesn't explicitly define is a bad idea in the first place, and this very much is an example of why.

Comment: That said, if you want to force something to a child process, you'll have a more reliable time of it to use a subshell, not a pipline. `a=5; (a=0; (( a++ )); b=1); echo $a` has a *guaranteed* result, not an experimentally-determined one.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh yes, this `a=0; (a=1); echo $a` returns 0 as expected

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scope a change to a child process, make that explicit.

```
a=5; (a=0); echo $a
```

Unlike a pipeline, which has behavior undefined by POSIX (and thus which each shell can decide how to handle heuristically), explicit subshell syntax with `(` ... `)` is entirely, *portably* unambiguous.